# Manipulate File Descriptors for select.select in Python

Tags: python, sockets, select, blocking, file-descriptor

I have an itching problem I know could be solved using many different ways, but I would still like to know if the following approach is possible in Python.

Suppose I have some socket I am constantly waiting for input on, and there is some condition that eventually terminates the whole program. I want to do it in a BLOCKING fashion, as I imagined, using select.select:

```
readfds, writefds, errfds = select.select([mysocket],[],[])
if readfds:
    conn, addr = mysocket.accept()
    ...
```

Now, if there is some file descriptor fd, that I can manually set to a ready condition, either read or write, I can do

```
readfds, writefds, errfds = select.select([mysocket,fd],[],[])
for r in readfds:
    if r == mysocket:
        conn, addr = mysocket.accept()
        ...
    else:
        <terminate>
```

Of course, I can simply send a message to mysocket, causing it to unblock but I would still like to know if there is a programmatic way to manipulate a file descriptor to a ready state.

EDIT: My question is: can I somehow set a file descriptor to "ready" manually?

Thanks all.

Comment: Yes, your code would work. Have you tried it? What problems did you find?

Comment: Oh I guess, my question was how to set this "fd" to ready manually.. if I simply open a file it is always readable/writable.

Comment: "I guess, my question was how to set this "fd" to ready manually"?  If that's your question, please actually **update** the words you posted to reflect what your actual question is, please.

Comment: "file descriptor to "ready" manually"?  You mean by writing data to the file so that data can be read?  Yes.  Write data to the file so that data can be read.  The easiest way to do this is for the FD to be -- not surprisingly -- a socket.  Is that what you're asking?  How to open a second socket for admin/control purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is probably to use [`os.mkfifo()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.mkfifo) to create a file pair, add the read end to the `select()` call, and then write to the write end when you want to unblock.

Also, you might want to consider just adding a timeout to the `select()` call; I can't imagine that you'd be doing enough during the unblocked time to drag performance down.

Comment: Thanks that's the type of thing I was looking for. Learned something new today!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will have to create a socket pair (see the `socket.socketpair()` function) and spawn a separate Python thread (use the `threading.Thread` class) to watch for the special condition that tells your program when to end.  When the thread detects the condition, it can write "Done!" (or whatever) on to its end of the socket pair.  If you have the other end of the socket pair in the list of sockets you are waiting on for reading, then it will light up and say that it is readable as soon as the "Done!" appears and is ready to be read off of the socket.

Answer (score 0):

Using an unnamed pipe [os.pipe()](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.html#os.pipe) would also work well here (block on the read end, write to the write end) and keep you from having to specify a path.

I've found this sort of setup useful with multiple threads, when I want one thread to be able to interrupt another thread's blocking on a select call.